# How do I Initialize a vector of lists of objects. Confusing I know

Tags: c++, list, vector

I am creating a sort of very crude `hashtable`. It will read an ASCII text file and store all the words into a table of linked lists along with the line numbers that word is found. It uses the numerical value of the first letter of the word to find the list to store the word, then searches the list for any entry of the word, if none is found it adds a new entry to the list otherwise it adds the line number to the entry that matches.

I just have no idea how to initialize a `vector`. It needs 128 lists (one for each ASCII value).

*Also note that I am not able to use `std::map`*

I know with a vector of ints you can do `vector<int> vector_name(128,0)` to get 128 entries all with value 0. I essentially want to do this but with 128 empty lists of `entry`'s.

Here is the code I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class index_table {
    public:
        void insert(string key, int value);
        vector<int>& find(string key);
    private:

        class entry{
            public:
                string word;
                list<int> line_numbers;
        };

        vector<list<entry> > table;
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use map but this is actually for an assignment and it had these specific instructions of how to store the data.

Comment: Initialize or assign? And which version of C++? Modern C++ supports initialization, older C++ is a pain in the butt for initialization of vector.

Comment: I guess you can use a `std::vector<std::pair<int, entry>>` it should work just like a `std::map<int, entry>` when iterating it.

Comment: I figured the default constructor would work since its just a string and a list. Nothing special.

Comment: Anyway, to insert a new element to your vector, you only have to do `table.push_back(new_object_of_type_entry_you_want_in_there)`. I've seen some codes intiializing the vector by doing `table.clear()`, but I don't think its required.

Comment: Anyway, if you already know you need exactly 128 elements in your vector, why are you not using an array? Like `list<entry> tables[128]`

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor that you don't yet have you could do : `table.resize(128);` now `table` is a vector of 128 empty `std::list`'s of `entry` objects.

i.e.

```
class index_table {
public:
    void insert(string key, int value);
    vector<int>& find(string key);

    //My ctor
    index_table(size_t len) : table(len), len(len) 
    {
        //some other stuff someday
    }

private:

    //not sure why you want to make entry private but ok...
    class entry{
        public:
            string word;
            list<int> line_numbers;
    };

    //some typename convenience for your iterators
    typedef entrylist list<entry>;
    typedef entrytable vector<entrylist>;
    entrytable table;
};
```

Comment: so if I wanted to check a value could i do

table[2].entry.word  ?.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by check a value?
`table[i]` will return to you a reference to the i'th list of entry objects

Comment: like if i need to compare the value of word in an entry object. Or simply access it.

Comment: do you know what a list is and how it works? You have to iterate over the list of entry objects at each index and compare them which is why you should probably make entry more than a dumb data structrue, and you should probably work on that insert function.

Comment: Sorry yah, I had forgotten. Dont ask me why they want us to do it this way but they do. Ive just confused myself, i need to break everything down into small steps and i think ill get it. Just daunting to think about.